# How can I exclude WooCommerce checkout from sending user profile change emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-notifications

We have a shop that is connected to a item management software. It exports its data via csv (WP All Export).

Now we have a function that fills a users description field with a text when profile data is changed.

Only users with this text get exported in the csv and once exported, the text ist gone and it isn't exported until the next change. It also fires an email when data is changed.

**The problem is:** This email is also sent every time the user orders something, even when his profile data stays the same. This has to be avoided.

Is there a way to exclude the checkout from firing this email?

The mentioned function is below:

```php
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {    
    
    if (!defined( 'WP_IMPORTING' ) ) { 
    
        $user_geaendert = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_geaendert', false );

        if (!strpos($user_geaendert, 'Export')) {

            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', 'seit letztem Export geändert ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));          
            
            $to = 'email@email.de';
            $subject = "Benutzerdaten geändert";
            $message =  'Benutzer mit der ID '.$user_id.' hat seine Daten geändert. domain.com/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id='.$user_id;       
            
            wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            
        }
    }   else {
        
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', '');
    }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
//add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
//add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_profile_update' );


function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
        
    
        $site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');  
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    
    
        $user_meta  =   get_userdata($user_id); 
        $user_roles =   $user_meta->roles; 
        
        if (in_array("customer", $user_roles)){
            $user_roles = 'customer';
        }
    
    
        if (get_user_meta( $user_id, 'anu_new_user_pass' , true ) != '' && $user_roles == 'customer') {
            
            $to = $user_info->user_email;
            $subject = "Freischaltung bei XXX";
            $message = "Sehr geehrte/r Nutzer/in,

    Ihr Benutzerkonto auf xxx.de wurde nun von uns freigeschaltet.

    Bitte loggen Sie sich mit Ihren Zugangsdaten ein. Ihre Kundennummer finden Sie in Ihrem Benutzerprofil.<br><br>
    Login: domain.com/mein-konto/ <br>
    Benutzername: ".get_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname' , true ) . "<br>
    Passwort: ".get_user_meta( $user_id, 'anu_new_user_pass' , true );
            
            
            wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            
        }
        
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Make use of a [conditional Tag](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/), `is_checkout()` - Returns true on the checkout page. So `if ( ! is_checkout() ) {...`

Comment: Thanks. Would I just wrap the whole `function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {...}` function inside of it? Would I need another add_action that replaces `add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );`?

Comment: it depends on which part of the code may or may not be executed within the hook, if it only concerns the mail function, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Added [`is_checkout()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_checkout.html) - Returns true when viewing the checkout page.
- Code has been cleaned up by adding comments with explanations

```php
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {    
    // NOT defined
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_IMPORTING' ) ) { 
        // Get user meta
        $user_geaendert = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_geaendert', false );

        // Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string, Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.
        if ( ! strpos( $user_geaendert, 'Export' ) ) {
            // Update user meta
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', 'seit letztem Export geändert ' . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ); 

            // NOT on the checkout page
            if ( ! is_checkout() ) {       
                // Mail parameters
                $to = 'email@email.de';
                $subject = "Benutzerdaten geändert";
                $message =  'Benutzer mit der ID ' . $user_id . ' hat seine Daten geändert. domain.com/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=' . $user_id;
                
                // Sends an email, similar to PHP’s mail function.
                wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
            }               
        }
    } else {
        // Update user meta
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', '');
    }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```